# Removing null values in PL/SQL table

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

I have a PL/SQL table having only business days generated at runtime

```
 L_busdays(1)=27-NOV-15
 L_busdays(3)=25-NOV-15
 L_busdays(4)=24-NOV-15
 L_busdays(5)=23-NOV-15
 L_busdays(8)=20-NOV-15
 L_busdays(9)=19-NOV-15
```

This is generated in runtime and there are some values missing like `L_busdays(2)`, `L_busdays(6)` and `L_busdays(7)` as they are holidays and weekends.

I need to generate another PL/SQL table so that I can go back and forth on data like below:

```
L_busdays(1)=27-NOV-15
L_busdays(2)=25-NOV-15
L_busdays(3)=24-NOV-15
L_busdays(4)=23-NOV-15
L_busdays(5)=20-NOV-15
L_busdays(6)=19-NOV-15
```

I am not able to achieve it. I always get no data found error for missing values and even if I assign to another table by handling the no data found the other table also has the exact copy of the primary data defeating the whole purpose. Please help me how to go about it. This is needed at run time.

```
for j in 1..L_busdays.COUNT 
loop 
  begin 
    L_busdays_sec(l):=L_busdays(j); 
  exception 
    when no_data_found then 
      null; 
  end; 
  l:=l+1; 
end loop;
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you're currently using, which generates an error? And how you're populating the original collection? Not sure if you need to preserve both, or fixing the initial generation would be enough.

Comment: for j in 1..L_busdays.COUNT 
loop 
begin 
L_busdays_sec(l):=L_busdays(j); 
exception 
when others then 
null; 
end; 
l:=l+1; 
end loop;

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show the code, don't put it in comments. Squashing errors with `when others` is a really bad idea though.

Comment: @SureshSundaram `exception when others then null;` Take a pledge to remember that it is itself a bug in your code. Read [**WHEN OTHERS - A Bug**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/) And also read this by the master himself **Thomas Kyte**, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1155066278457

Comment: Hi   I have edited the code. Lalit i know that we should not give when others just was thinking about the logic to arrive at. This is not my final code. I need the assignment logic of one plsql table to others . Please help!

Comment: Please note that questions on StackOverflow are answered by volunteers.  You have no SLA with us and you are not entitled to an immediate response.  Also, note that you are more likely to get a quick response if you post a complete example instead of some code snippets  *which don't even compile*.  If you are not prepared to invest your time in framing a decent question why should other people spend their time trying to answer it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a new collection to navigate a sparse collection such as  business days (unless you need it for some other purpose).  Simply use the `NEXT()` method to go forwards to the next entry and `PRIOR()` to go backwards.

```
declare
    type l_days_nt is table of date 
        index by pls_integer;
    L_busdays l_days_nt;
    idx pls_integer;
begin
    -- populate collection
    L_busdays(1):=to_date('27-NOV-15');
    L_busdays(3):=to_date('25-NOV-15');
    L_busdays(4):=to_date('24-NOV-15');
    L_busdays(5):=to_date('23-NOV-15');
    L_busdays(8):=to_date('20-NOV-15');
    L_busdays(9):=to_date('19-NOV-15');
    dbms_output.put_line('navigate collection forwards ...');
    idx := L_busdays.first();
    while idx is not null
    loop 
       dbms_output.put_line('idx #'||idx||'='||to_char(L_busdays(idx))); 
       idx := L_busdays.next(idx);
    end loop; 
    dbms_output.put_line('.... and backwards'); 
    idx := L_busdays.last();
    while idx is not null
    loop 
       dbms_output.put_line('idx #'||idx||'='||to_char(L_busdays(idx))); 
       idx := L_busdays.prior(idx);
    end loop; 
end;
/
```

There's plenty about collection methods in the PL/SQL documentation.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99964)